# JavaFX stage sizing inconsistent when using SwingNodes

Tags: java, swing, javafx

**Problem:** I have Swing content that needs to be displayed using a JavaFX stage. The Swing content needs to be wrapped within a `ScrollPane` to preserve normal Swing sizing when the stage is resized.

**Expected Behavior:** When the stage is first shown, it needs to be sized automatically to fit the Swing content (i.e. without needing scrolling to view).

**Actual Behavior:** Either the stage shows the Swing content partially (if the stage is shown *before* the node is populated) or not shown at all (if the stage is shown *after* the node is populated).

If stage is shown *before* adding Swing-node content:

[image: if stage is shown *before*]

If stage is shown *after* adding Swing-node content and then resized:

[image: if stage is shown *after* and then resized]

**Code:** This may include a few redundant statements as part of my various attempts.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Platform.startup(() -> {});
    Platform.runLater(() -> doSwingNodeTest());
}

protected static void doSwingNodeTest() {
    final Stage stage = new Stage();
    final ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    final SwingNode node = new SwingNode();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show(); // Required here for any content to 
                  //display without resizing.
    stage.sizeToScene();

    final JPanel j = new JPanel();
    j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    j.add(new JLabel("Some text"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    j.add(new JButton("Some button"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    j.add(new JButton("East button"), BorderLayout.EAST);

    node.setContent(j);
    j.revalidate();
    node.autosize();

    root.setContent(node);
    stage.setOnShown(e -> {
        j.doLayout();
        stage.sizeToScene();
        node.autosize();
        root.autosize();
    });
    // stage.show(); // Causes an 0-sized window.
}
```

Anyone have any clues as to what is going on and how to resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Adam Sorry, forgot to include that. Java 9, running on Windows 10

Comment: I recently raised a couple of sort-of related issues https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199204 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198677

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollPane`, together with `SwingNode`, can be quite troublesome to control. This is what *probably* happened:

1. The `ScrollPane` is the root node, so the `Scene` needs to tell the `ScrollPane` how much space it can give to the `ScrollPane`.
2. The `Scene` tells the `ScrollPane` that it can use any amount of space (`Scene` will try to resize itself during the initial layout).
3. The `ScrollPane` needs to tell its children to do its layout. Since the `ScrollPane` can spawn scroll bars when needed, it will simply tell the children to use as much space as it wants.
4. The children, which is the `SwingNode`, has no content to render in the layout phase, and it will tell `ScrollPane` that it needs to use X amount of space, which is some kind of default.
5. The `ScrollPane` resizes itself to that size.
6. The `ScrollPane` tells the `Scene` that it needs that much space.
7. The `Scene` and `Stage` sets their sizes accordingly.
8. `Stage` becomes visible, and all contents start to render.
9. `SwingNode` starts rendering the Swing components.
10. The Swing components need bigger space and request from `SwingNode`.
11. `SwingNode` requests for space from `ScrollPane`.
12. `ScrollPane` creates the scroll bars and continues to render its children in the small space.

As for solution, I did not manage to find any decent ones. One way is to set a fixed size somewhere (`Scrollpane`, `Scene` or `SwingNode`). The other way is to move the scrolling into Swing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, moving the scrolling into Swing doesn't quite work because the Swing-world doesn't ever seem to be notified that it's viewport is limiting and therefore the scrollbars need to displayed... The curious thing is my original code worked in a different application context... Which, combined with your breakdown of events, makes me wonder if there's a specific event sequence that can make it work. I've been trying to step through the two versions but can't quite trace where the differences are

Comment: @anishthecoder I'm not too familiar with Swing because I haven't touch much of that in recent years. If there is some kind of toolkit or helper that can calculate the Swing component sizes before they are rendered, you can use that to set the preferred size of the `SwingNode`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to simply ask the SwingNode how big its content should be via getPreferredSize() and then use that value to set the size of the stage. I'm currently investigating why fudge variable is needed.

```
protected static void doSwingNodeTest() {
    final Stage stage = new Stage();
    final SwingNode node = new SwingNode();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new ScrollPane(node)));

    final JPanel j = new JPanel();
    j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    j.add(new JLabel("Some text"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    j.add(new JButton("Some button"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    j.add(new JButton("East button"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    node.setContent(j);

    int fudge = 10;
    stage.setWidth(fudge + node.getContent().getPreferredSize().getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(fudge + node.getContent().getPreferredSize().getHeight());
    stage.show(); 

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when I run it as is: https://imgur.com/a/UrApr

Comment: Works fine using Java 9 on OS X. Can you try adding this VM parameter.... -Dprism.allowhidpi=false